# In gnome shell , How to revise command of software icon?

Tags: gnome

I want to add a parameter to a software .
How to add parameter to command line of software icon?
I use ubuntu11.10.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean exactly? Do you want to add a parameter to the application behind the icon, so each time you run the application by clicking on the icon, the application is run along with the parameter? If that is what you mean, you should do as follows:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `alacarte`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If `alacarte` hasn't been installed yet, you should first type `sudo apt-get install alacarte` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Navigate to the application you want to add a parameter to, and click on *Properties*.
4. Edit the third rule (the command line) to add a parameter. For example, if you want to use `chromium` in private mode each time it starts, change `/usr/bin/chromium-browser %U` to `/usr/bin/chromium-browser %U --incognito` (`incognito` is the parameter for private browsing in `chromium`).
5. Click on *Close*, and click another time on *Close* in `alacarte`.